# Display 0 as blank in a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

How can i display a value of `0` as blank in a pivot table. The column I wish to apply this to is formatted as a date. And anything with a value 0 displays as `00/01/1900`.

I tried conditional formatting to simply display zero with a white font, this worked until the data changes in the pivot,

I tried a custom number format: `dd/mm/yyyy;;""` This had the same issues as conditional Formatting.

Are there any other things I can try ?
Bare in mind, the pivot table will change its results every day, so I need something that will have a permanent fix.

P.S I cannot just filter out the 0s, as there is information I need from other columns in the same Row as a 0 etc.

Comment: Could you use an IF() statement? IF(A1=0;"";DATE) or similar. Im not to familiar with Pivot Tables.

Comment: I could probably do that in the source data I suppose, but I don't really want to mess with that as I may not always be the person populating.

Comment: A similar question provides [multiple approaches for dealing with this type of problem.](https://superuser.com/questions/515932/display-blank-when-referencing-blank-cell-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is in the File Options.

See if un-checking the `Show a zero in cells that have zero value` helps.

```
File > Options > Advanced
```

Under the `Display options for this workbook` heading (scroll about ¾ of the way down)

It helped me before when I had a similar issue. Though, unfortunately, I can't seem to recreate the problem. Anyone know what causes this issue?

Anyhow, PeterH, I hope the Options solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks @James, this is the work around i had used, only down side is the anywhere outside the pivot that is a 0 now displays as blank also, but i can live with that,