# Robust linking of cells Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, links, cells

Is there a way to link cells so that not only content updates automatically, but also format (fill, border, font, etc.)?

Also, is there a way, other than doing each cell individually, to avoid blank cells in my source sheet to show as 0 on my current sheet? I have a big file with a lot of random blank cells that I don't want to link as 0.

Thanks.

Comment: *not only content updates automatically, but also format* What the values and formats are updated by? macro? VBA? external prog? *to avoid blank cells in my source sheet to show as 0* To show or to store? In the first case You may use conditional formatting for zeroes as white-by-white, for example...

Comment: @Akina Sorry. This might be a very basic question comparing to how you answered. I was previously linking cells by "=", but this only updates the contents, not the format. Also, a blank cell in the source will update the current as 0. Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way..

Comment: Oh. I understand "linking" not as reference, but as cells merge.

Comment: Well. To copy format from source to destination You may use Worksheet_Change procedure (when formula is simple -  You know destination, but You are to obtain source address for format copying). To hide zero values You may convert formula '=A1' to '=IF(A1=0,'',A1)'. Of course, it slightly increase data recalculations...

Comment: Your second question is covered somewhat exhaustively  in [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/515932/150988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other Users have explained, the only way to have a "linked" cell that auto-updates its format when the source cell's format changes is to use VBA.

However, if the only thing you wish to do is directly mirror a source cell without any other calculations (e.g., you just want to do `=A1` but also have the formats update), there ***is*** a way to make it *look* like that's what's happening.

Just four simple steps:

1. Select the source range
2. Copy
3. Select the top left cell of the destination range
4. Paste as a Picture Link (`Home → Clipboard → Paste → As Picture → Paste Picture Link`)

The following screenshots show how to create a picture link at `D11` linked to `D2:E3` and how it looks when the picture is deselected:

[image: Screenshot during picture link creation] [image: Screenshot after picture link creation]

**Notes:**

Unfortunately you can't actually *use* the values from the picture for any further calculations.

However, there is a work-around for this. Just directly link the cells underneath the picture to the source as well. In my example above, you would enter `=D2` into cell `D11` and ctrl-enter/fill/copy-paste that formula into `D11:E12`.

The only issue with this work-around is that blank source cells will show through the picture as `0`s if the source cell's fill is set to `No Fill`.

To work-around this `0` issue, either set the destination cells' font colour to the fill colour (use white for no fill), or, if you actually require the destination to actually *be* "blank", use the formula `=IF(D2="","",D2)` instead of `=D2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know VBA, you could set up a macro that runs when any of the cells in a range are changed, and apply the same formatting to another range. If not, depending on the details of what you're trying to do, you could potentially use conditional formatting that applies to both ranges. If you clarify what you need, I'll update my answer.

As for the blank/0 issue, you can use the `IF` and `ISBLANK` formulas. For example:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)
```

will return an empty string if A1 is blank, otherwise it will return the value of A1.

Comment: IsBlank() will not hide zeroes obtained from space-only, hidden symbols, etc...

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry but you are completely wrong ;-) `=A1` only returns a zero incorrectly when `A1` is blank (i.e., there is no formula, no spaces-only, no nothing in `A1`). `=ISBLANK(A1)` only returns `TRUE` if `A1` is blank. So `=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)` will convert all incorrectly returned zeroes to null strings. *"space-only, hidden symbols, etc"* are **not** converted to zeroes so `ISBLANK()` does **not** need to worry about "hiding" them. (As they never existed to start off with ;-) )