# Excel interprets percentage inputs inconsistently

Tags: microsoft-excel, input, numpad

I am inputting numbers into a cell that is formatted to display the number as percentage.

I desire to enter 10%, so I type “10” into the cell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The cell now displays 10% (great).

I desire to enter 0.2%, so I type “0.2” into the cell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, now the cell displays 20%!

This behavior seems inconsistent. Is there are way to ensure it always behaves as the former?

If I type “0.2**%**” and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> I get what I desire, but this is slightly tedious because I can't use the numpad for fast input. Also, there is a good chance I'll forget to add the “%” manually and input data incorrectly.

Comment: If you are typing the `0` in the `0.2` it puts in `0.2%` for me.  Only when typing `.2` without the `0` does it return `20%`

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. From your public data I see that you have not yet visited the [tour]. Please do so, and read it to the end, it only takes a minute. And since your question has been answered, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Please specify what version of Excel you are using.

1. When I do what you describe in Excel 2013, I get the desired result;
   i.e., if I enter “0.2”, I get “0.20%”. 
   If I enter “**.**2”, without the leading zero, I get “20.00%”. 
   So, if you made an error when typing your question,
   and you typed “**.**2” when you got “20.00%”,
   then the answer is to always type the leading zero
   when entering a value less than 1%. 
   This allows you to keep your hand on the numeric keypad.

   But still has the drawback that you have to remember to do it every time,
   and if you forget to do it, Excel will happily, quietly (with no warning)
   give you the wrong answer.
2. Another approach is *not* to format the cells as Percentage
   until after you’ve done the data entry. 
   Leave them with the default format (“General”),
   or format them as Number, if you prefer. 
   Enter the numbers you want,
   e.g., “20”, “17”, “10”, “7.2”, “2”, “**.**2”, etc. 
   Then, when you’re done, divide them all by 100 and format them as Percentage.

   This should solve your problem if your workflow calls for a data entry phase,
   followed by some sort of analysis / display phase
   in which the percentages are unchanged. 
   If your workflow requires frequent updating of the percentages,
   this might not be helpful.

   ---

   How do you do the same arithmetic operation (e.g., divide by 100)
   to a range of cells? 
   Here’s a couple of ways. 
   (I’ll assume that the numbers that you want to manipulate
   are in cells `A2:A100`.)

   - Pick a column that you aren’t using; say, `Q`.
     Enter `=A2/100` in cell `Q2` and drag/fill down to `Q100`. 
     Then copy cells `Q2:Q100` and paste values into `A2:A100`.
   - Pick a cell that you aren’t using; say, `Q17`.
     Enter `100` in cell `Q17` and “Copy” it. 
     Then select cells `A2:A100`
     and do “Paste” → “Paste Special” → “Divide”.

   In either case you will probably need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
   to dismiss the selection. 
   You might then also want
   to clear the cell(s) you used temporarily.

   Both of these approaches have the issue
   that blank cells will be turned into zeroes. 
   Ways of addressing this issue are discussed
   in [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/515932/150988).
3. Yet another approach is to maintain two columns in perpetuity. 
   Pick a column that you aren’t using. 
   For example, if your percentage numbers are in Column `P`,
   then you might choose Column `Q` (or `AP`). 
   Enter `=Q2/100` in cell `P2`, format as Percentage,
   and drag/fill down. 
   Then enter your raw data (i.e., the numbers ranging from 0 to 100)
   into Column `Q`
   (which you will have left as “General”, or formatted as “Number”). 
   Do all your edits in Column `Q`. 
   Hide the extra column when you want to print.

Comment: Ah ok - I think for my workflow/preference using the leading zero is my best bet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a setting for 'smart percentages' - if this is on, it tries to think for you.

If you enter 10, it thinks 'you probably don't mean 1000%, so it should be 10%'; if you enter .2, it thinks 'you probably don't mean 0.2%, so it should be 20%'.

Switch the setting to off, and the behavior is consistent for all entries (it will always multiply by 100 to show percentages, so 10 will give 1000%)