# How can I select data and draw chart using a button in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my Excel workbook (i.e., file),
I have for example seven sheets (Mon, Tue ... Sun) of temperatures. 
This data is recorded for the whole day in a fixed frequency.

Now I want to create a tool to view this time series data easily.

My thinking is, I create a page, say, Index, which has the list of names of all these sheets, there is a chart object, which displays the data from sheet Mon by default, and a button/or a drop down list for me to change Mon to any name (which connect to the sheet), and refresh the chart to display the corresponding data.

How should I approach this? I am just a very basic Excel user, but I am willing to learn the skill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven’t given us detailed information
on how your sheets are laid out,
I’ll assume that you have times in cells `A2:A25`
and temperatures in cells `B2:B25` on each of your daily sheets, like this:

[image: Input data for Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday]

On your Index sheet, enter

- In `A1`, “Day”. 
  (This is just a label;
  the same as you have shown in your image of your desired result).
- In `B1`, your drop-down list of the days of the week.
- In `J1`, “Time”. 
  (This is just a label, and is optional.)
- In `K1`, “Temp”. 
  (This is just a label, and is optional.)
- In `L1`, `=B1 & " Temp"`. 
  This will be the chart title.
- In `J2:J25`, the times 00:00 through 23:00. 
  Or, if some sheets have different “X”-axis values
  (for example, if some days have 00:30 through 23:30),
  enter

      ```
      =IF(INDIRECT($B$1&"!A"&ROW())<>"", INDIRECT($B$1&"!A"&ROW()), "")
      ```

  in `J2` and drag/fill down to `J25`
  (assuming that you always have 24 data points). 
  You may need to manually format this correctly
  (e.g., `hh:mm`). 
  This will access time data (i.e., *X*-axis labels)
  from Column `A` of the indexed daily sheet,
  forcing empty cells to be treated as blank rather than zero
  (see [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/515932/150988#515941)).
- In `K2`,
  `=IF(INDIRECT($B$1&"!B"&ROW())<>"", INDIRECT($B$1&"!B"&ROW()), #N/A)`. 
  This will access temperature data
  from Column `B` of one of the daily sheets,
  replacing empty cells with `#N/A`
  (the “not available” pseudo-value),
  which will cause the corresponding data points
  not to be included in the chart. 
  Select `K2` and drag/fill down to `K25`. 
  The temperature data for the selected day will appear.

Now create your chart based on `J1:K25` of the Index sheet. 
Click on the chart title, and type `=Index!L1` into the formula bar. 
Then simply select the day that you want in `Index!B1`,
and the chart for that day’s data will automatically, immediately appear
— no need to press a button.

[image: Chart for Monday]

[image: Chart for Tuesday]

[image: Chart for Wednesday]

Sample result with missing data:

[image: Chart for Monday with missing data]

Of course the choice of cells is arbitrary. 
I used Columns `J` through `L`
so I could fit them on the page with the chart. 
If you’d rather *not* see the selected data,
use Columns `AA` through `AC` so they’ll be out of sight
— and/or hide the auxiliary columns.

Comment: Scott, why did you delete the sample image from OP?

Comment: Because I believed that it did nothing to clarify or illuminate the question.  All it shows (and not very clearly) is a choice among the days of the week, and a chart that (presumably) is based on data from the Monday page.  But the question says all that.  In my opinion, this picture is worth zero words.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't expect it can be this simple, just one key function in here, indirect. Many many thanks

Comment: May I also ask another question? in fact some days I have less data, for example, Mon until 22:00, Tue until 23:00, so data range is not fixed. If I use the max range, that means a short range will have zero value at the end, how can the chart ignore these zero value dynamically please?

Comment: I expanded my answer to cover your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vba macro, updating the chart-data. Without error-checking and most names for a better understanding

```
Private Sub SetChart(sheetChrt as worksheet, sheetData as worksheet)
 With sheetChrt.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
   .XValues = sheetData.Range("A1:A10") '
   .Values = sheetData.Range("B1:B10")
 End With
End Sub

Public Sub Test1()
 with Thisworkbook
 SetChart .Sheets("MyChartSheet"), .Sheets("MyDataSheet")
 end with
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is worth to learn.