# How do I populate an Excel 2010 cell when a different cell is manually populated the same worksheet but a different tab?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How do I auto populate an Excel 2010 cell when a different cell is manually populated in the same worksheet but a different tab?

Comment: By worksheet, do you mean workbook? The whole excel file is called workbook, and the tabs are actually worksheets. So in your question, I guess you mean 'same workbook' but different 'worksheet'.

Comment: Assuming we guessed the terminology, it isn't clear what your question is.  Are you saying someone inputs a value in some cell, and you want a cell on another tab to show the same value?  If so, just stick a reference there to the input cell, as in wrecclesham's answer (you would need to preface it with `=` to make it a formula instead of just a bunch of text).  If you want the second cell to remain blank until there is input in the first cell, you can use IF: `=IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A1),"",Sheet2!A1)`.

Comment: Related: [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/q/515932/354511).

Answer (score 1):

To reference a single cell in another tab:

```
Sheet_name!Cell_address
```

E.g.

```
Sheet2!A1
```

To reference a range of cells in another tab:

```
Sheet_name!First_cell:Last_cell
```

E.g.

```
Sheet2!A1:B2
```