# I have a formula in excel and want it to return blank if referenced cell is blank and not a "0"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Some of the referenced cells are blank and I would like that to be carried over instead of returning "0" in the cell

This is my formula -

=VLOOKUP(B2, SKUs!A$2:$E$7, 3, FALSE)

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/515932/display-blank-when-referencing-blank-cell-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Hide or display all zero values on a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)

> Click File > Options > Advanced.
>
> Under Display options for this worksheet, select a worksheet, and then
> do one of the following:
>
> - To display zero (0) values in cells, check the Show a zero in cells
>   that have zero value check box.
> - To display zero (0) values as blank cells, uncheck the Show a zero in
>   cells that have zero value check box.

This can be done per-worksheet or workbook - I don't believe it can be specified per-function.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$E$7,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$E$7,3,FALSE))
```

or, if you have office 365

```
=LET(x,VLOOKUP(B2,$A$2:$E$7,3,FALSE),IF(x="","",x))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help guys!