# i want to return value( eg;- sum) only if the source is not blank,other wise return blank !!not zero!! in excel, wps

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, wps-spreadsheet

**see this screenshot for reference**
[see this screenshot..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnkxg.png)

I used SUM formula in the botton cells to get sum of all values from each row , the bottom cells display TOTAL

> and i will assign the TOTAL cells in the form of  "1" / "0"(on/off) !!( NOT TO DISPLAY...)
> using  " =IF(ISBLANK(cell ID),0,1)  " this type formula

Comment: something like `IF(SUM(A2:A6)>0,SUM(A2:A6),"")`?

Comment: @AlexM let me try.

Comment: @AlexM how exactly to call this formula for more than 2 range of cells ?

Comment: @Musawir_ap you would put that in the first cell and copy/drag it over.

Comment: @Musawir_ap  literally you don't have black cells in fact you want to SUM only Positive values or values greater than Zero ,,, use formula suggested by Alex or {=IF(A2:A6>0,SUM(A2:A6),"") } & finish with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and fill Right,,.

Comment: @RajeshS don't i have any blancells? have you seen the screenshot? aren't blank cells in table literally blank cells?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/515932/display-blank-when-referencing-blank-cell-in-excel-2010)

Comment: @Musawir_ap yeah I've seen that's Y suggested the formula try once it will work for U!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, this is an array formula you need to enter the formula and end with **SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER**

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2:A6)=TRUE,"",SUM(A2:A6))
```

[image]