# No answer if cell blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm subtracting 2 dates.  If the dates are <=5 then the answer is Y, if not then the answer is N.   How do I ignore blank cells so I don't automatically get a Y?  This is the formula I'm using.

=IF(G2-C2<=5,"Y","N")

Comment: Add a second  IF for your "N" case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/515932/display-blank-when-referencing-blank-cell-in-excel-2010)

Comment: It doesn't ignore the blanks, but you might be able to use an absolute value.  ABS(G2-C2)<=5.  If either cell is blank, you'll get a value much greater than 5.  Also, with an absolute value, the order of the dates won't matter which can be appropriate for some uses.

Answer (score 1):

One way among many others is to use ISBLANK, OR, and nested IFs:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(G2)),"",IF(G2-C2<=5,"Y","N"))
```

Comment: @Julie Wood, when the only cell in column C is blank, it will automatically get "N", but when the only cell in column G is blank, it will automatically get "Y". You could also choose to use the ISBLANK function for column G only. Also note that when G2-C2 is negative, "Y" will also be returned.